# Unable to communicate between Android client and Node.js socket.io server

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've looked at many tutorials on this yet none of them seem to work so no idea whether it's the server, client or potentially something on my network that's stopping it I don't know, so I come here for help.

Just for reference this is the tutorial that this is mainly based on: https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

So this is my server. All it's supposed to do at the moment is detect when a user connects and then detect users sending messages and send them back to all the clients.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server listening at 3000");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected");

   socket.on("new message", (data) => {
       console.log("New message" + data)

       socket.emit("new message", {
           message: data
       });
   })
});
```

My Android client is made up of 3 classes. But to try and keep this shorter I'll only include 2 of them as if the problem can be found in these it's fixable in the 3rd.

This is what's launched at the start and simply pressing the button brings you to the main 'chat' part, but on clicking the button the server should log the connection but nothing appears in the console. So I can only assume the socket connection isn't working for some reason. Also you can ignore the nickname, I've not implemented that yet, been trying to get the main part working first.

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nickname;
    private Button enterChat;

    private Socket mSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nickname = findViewById(R.id.nickname);
        enterChat = findViewById(R.id.enterChat);

        ChatApplication app = (ChatApplication) getApplication();
        mSocket = app.getSocket();
        mSocket.connect();

        enterChat.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mSocket.emit("connection");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", nickname.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        });
    }
}
```

This is just to be able to get the Socket from any other activity.

ChatApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class ChatApplication extends Application {
    private Socket mSocket;
    {

        try {
                                      //My IPv4 address here
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I need to add this to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
</application>
```